# Add a custom column to My Account Orders table in Woocommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, orders

Woocommerce 3.5.x has a special page at the user account (My Account) area where it displays the user's previous Orders.

This page is now 5 column displays as default.

Here the screenshot of the woocommerce Orders area with 5 column:

[My Orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er9FR.png)

I Can't find the way to change this.

How can I add a new column in the default?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This requires 2 functions that will add a new column *(still working in WooCommerce 8.1+)*

The second function hook is a composite hook: `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_{$column_id}` where `{$column_id}` need to be replaced by the column key slug that is set in the first function.

That second function manage the displayed row values and you can add for example a custom field to get custom order meta data values.

The code:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'add_account_orders_column', 10, 1 );
function add_account_orders_column( $columns ){
    $order_actions  = $columns['order-actions']; // Save Order actions
    unset($columns['order-actions']); // Remove Order actions

    // Add your custom column key / label
    $columns['custom-column'] = __( 'New Column', 'woocommerce' );

    // Add back previously saved "Order actions"
    $columns['order-actions'] = $order_actions;

    return $columns;
}

// Display a custom field value from order metadata
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom-column', 'add_account_orders_column_rows' );
function add_account_orders_column_rows( $order ) {
    // Example with a custom field
    if ( $value = $order->get_meta( '_custom_field' ) ) {
        esc_html_e( $value );
    } else {
        printf( '<small>%s</small>', __("no value") );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

You are done and have added a custom column to My account orders table:

[image]

> If you which to make changes in the table html output, you will have to override the template file: `myaccount/orders.php`

Comment: Don't add that as a comment, add it as an answer instead. And please remove those comments, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't wanna change the order template under myaccount page. Here's what you have to do.

**First:**

```
function wc_add_myaccount_order_column( $columns ) {
    $columns[ 'custom-column' ] = __( 'Custom Column', 'woocommerce' );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'wc_add_myaccount_order_column' );
```

**Second:**

```
function wc_custom_column_display( $order ) {
    // do something here
    echo "testing";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom-column', 'wc_custom_column_display' );
```

The code above will display *"testing"* in each order under *"Custom Column"* column.

*Note: If you actually wanna change the entire template, like the design for example. You can follow the first answer above.*

Answer (score 1):

Just to improve the accepted answer I add a line to choose the position of the column (after total):

```
function sv_wc_add_my_account_orders_column( $columns ) {

    $new_columns = array();

    foreach ( $columns as $key => $name ) {

        $new_columns[ $key ] = $name;

        // add ship-to after order status column
        if ( 'order-total' === $key ) {  //this is the line!
            $new_columns['custom-column'] = __( 'Custom Column', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }

    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'sv_wc_add_my_account_orders_column' );


    function wc_custom_column_display( $order ) {
        // do something here
        echo "testing";
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom-column', 'wc_custom_column_display' );
```

Answer (score 0):

With WooCommerce 5.9, I couldn't get LiocTheAztect's answer to work. What worked for me was:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 
'add_customer_email_column');
    function add_customer_email_column( $columns ){
        $new_columns = [
        "order-number" => $columns["order-number"],
        // ...
        "customer-email" => __( 'Customer Email', '' ),
        // ...
        "order-actions" => $columns["order-actions"]
    ];
    return $new_columns;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_customer-email', 
'add_customer_email_content' );
    function add_customer_email_content($order) {
    echo esc_html($order->get_billing_email());
}
```

Without the `if ($value = $order->get_meta( '_custom_field' ))` block. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

Default column IDs are `order-number` for the Order ID column, `order-date`, `order-status`, `order-total`, and `order-actions`. Use it like `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-actions` hook.