# woocommerce — How to change column name in a table?

Tags: woocommerce

how to change column name in my orders table

[image]

Comment: This post should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623789/add-a-custom-column-to-my-account-orders-table-in-woocommerce-3

Comment: Thank you, this is not what I want, but help me find the solution and I will write the solution in Post below

Answer (score 0):

this is solution

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'add_account_orders_column', 10, 1 );function add_account_orders_column( $columns ){
$columns = array(
    'order-number'       => __( 'OrderTest', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-date'         => __( 'DateTest', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-status'       => __( 'StatusTest', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-total'        => __( 'TotalTest', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-actions'      => __( 'ActionsTest', 'woocommerce' ),
);
return $columns;}
```